# How to pass data from android Service (from onStart or OnCreate) to android Activity

Tags: android, service

How to pass data from android Service (from onStart or OnCreate) to android Activity. I would like to pass data from inside the service using `setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)` to the sender (service started activity) to `OnActivityResult()` method.

Comment: If the above scenario doesnot work then can I send data with intent instead of setResult(), because setResult() is used for startActivityForResult(); Or else can I use sendBroadCast() method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you start the activity from the service? if so why cant you just place the data inside the intent?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("DataToBePassed", "some data here..");
startActivity(intent);
```

setResult is only when you start the activity via startActivityForResult and you set the result in the activity that is called. not on the service, the service is the one that will get the result.

do read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html for more info.

Comment: I think you may have confused with my question. Simply, I would like to pass data from inside the service ( From OnCreate or OnStart Method) to the activity in the current application. As per my knowledge I am unable to send data directly to the activity as you said above. My doubt is whether do we need to any thing like sendbroadcast() method or do we need to use anything like IBinder method to do so?

Comment: to communicate with the service you should bind to it. you could also use the sendbroadcast method both should work well. the best approach is still to bind to the service though..

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface.
Like

```
public interface YourCallback {
    public void onSuccess(String result);
}
```

> Then use in anywhere .I used om my onPostExecute method.

```
yourCallback.onSuccess(result);
```

> And use activity oncreate

```
new YourAsyncTask(new YourAsyncTas() {

     @Override
     public void onSuccess(String result) {
      yourGlobalFeald=result;

     }
    }).execute(if you want to use executable method);
```